# Naive question about bootstrap

Tags: self-study, bootstrap

I've just started learning about bootstrap methods in the context of econometrics.  In Davidson and Mackinnon's "Econometric Theory and Methods," (pg. 167) they compare the results of an asymptotic $t$ test with parametric and semi parametric bootstrap methods.  They use a simple regression model with a lagged dependent variable

$$
y_t = \beta_1 + \beta_2 X_t + \beta_3 y_{t-1} + u_t, \qquad u_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2)
$$

and $\beta_3=0.9$.  With many replications, they find that the asymptotic t test overrejects the null compared with the bootstrap, although its (t-test) performance improves as the sample size gets larger.  They acknowledge this example may be misleading in demonstrating the performance of bootstrap compared to asymptotic tests, but my question is: In an era where all statistical computation is done by computers, is there ever a reason to not use bootstrap methods, if they seem to do so well? If I'm doing a regression, should I always use bootstrapping?

Comment: As a promoter of the bootstrap and an author on bootstrap methods, I like seeing its growing use.  But watch out the bootstrap does not always provide consistent estimates.  Examples of bootstrap failures are given in a chapter in my book  M. R. Chernick (2007) "Bootstrap Methods: A Practitioner's Guide"  published iby Wiley.